# how to apply custom validation on json value

Tags: json, scala, validation

I have a json data coming via api. I have set of policies that I need to validate over coming json data.

For Example I have a json like

```
{
"users_id":"x",
"is_user_logged_in":"true",
"checkin_date":"2018-12-12",
"checkout_date":"2019-12-13"
}
```

Now I want to apply validation like `checkin_date` should be less than `checkout_data` or let say if `is-user_logged_in` is true then `user_id` should not be null.

I cant deserialize the json as i need to pass it to different application to consume

I am using Scala any idea how can i implement this. The catch is there can be multiple policies or rules i need to validate and i can only get the rules in runtime.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a custom (de)serializer for your json data, you may implement it there. Just throw an exception if it the data is invalid and handle it properly.

Comment: @Aki I dont have serialiser that json is further pass to some different appliaction

Comment: You have to deserialize it in order to validate it. After validation, you just throw away the deserialized data.

Comment: @ygor can you give me  example for the same.

Comment: You have not tried anything yourself yet.

Comment: @ygor do you thing i haven't tried anything just post it for fun??

Comment: @AkashSethi Can you bring an example of a the format of the policy rule you might get in runtime?

Comment: Look into jsonpath https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2

Answer (score 2):

Most easier way is to add validation to the default constructor and just use the JSON parser as a validator (no need to use parsed data):

```
import java.time.LocalDate

case class UserData(
  user_id: Option[String],
  is_user_logged_in: Boolean,
  checkin_date: LocalDate,
  checkout_date: LocalDate
) {
  require(!is_user_logged_in || user_id.isDefined, "missing `user_id` for logged in user")
  require(checkout_date.isAfter(checkin_date), "`checkout_date` should be after `checkin_date`")
}
```

For more complicated cases please consider to use some handy validation library, like:

https://github.com/jto/validation

Comment: Thanks for answer but i am not generating json. this json is generated by someone else maybe via java, scala or any other language

Comment: The easier solution works for parsing too. Most of parsers can bind parsed JSON objects to instances of Scala case classes, so validation code in `require` functions will be called.

Comment: Just run the `main` method of example and the output bellow will be printed: 
Success(UserData(Some(x),true,2018-12-12,2019-12-13))
Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: `checkout_date` should be after `checkin_date`)
Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: missing `user_id` for logged in user)

Comment: I completely understand your answer and this is something i already know but issue is i have around 400 nested json fieds and i only know about the fields and data type case class is not there but there are multiple json not one hence this is not a solution if required please update question accordingly

Comment: 1) Just use the JSON parser as a validator (no need to use parsed data); 2) Do not need to know all possible fields, only that fields that need to be validated should be parsed (by default jsoniter-scala just skips all unknown fields and does it blazingly fast)